# How do I display my views output variable in my template in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have my Django views.py function :

```
def dsctbl2(request):
dynamodb=boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
response = dynamodb.scan(
TableName='User-Account')
 filtered = response['Items']
length = len(filtered)
a = []
for k in range(length):
  accnum = filtered[k]['AccountNum']['S']
  uid = filtered[k]['UserId']['S']
  f = {}
  f = dict(AccountNum=accnum,UserId=uid)
  a.append(f)
return (a)
```

The above function filters the UserId and Accountnumber items from a dynamodb table. I need to display the "UserId" and "AccountNum" in my html template in a table's row.

Here's my html snippet :

```
<div class="mytable">
   <table style="width:96%" class="table table-responsive">
     <thead id="head" class="mdb-color lighten-4">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="th-lg">User ID</th>
                    <th class="th-lg">Account Number</th>
                </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
              {% for r in rows %}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                  <td>{{r.AccountNum}}</td>
                  <td>{{r.UserId}}</td>
               </tr>
               {% endfor %}
            </tbody>

        </table>

</div>
```

I've included block content and endblock tags in my html code . What am I doing wrong here ? I'm a beginner in Django. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to render your output to your html file. Ex return render_to_response(your.html', {"rows":a})

Answer (score 0):

You need to render your output to your html file.

**Ex:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def dsctbl2(request):
    dynamodb=boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
    response = dynamodb.scan(
    TableName='User-Account')
    filtered = response['Items']
    length = len(filtered)
    a = []
    for k in range(length):
      accnum = filtered[k]['AccountNum']['S']
      uid = filtered[k]['UserId']['S']
      f = {}
      f = dict(AccountNum=accnum,UserId=uid)
      a.append(f)
    return render_to_response('your.html', {"rows":a})
```

Comment: Yes ! The page shows up now. I can see the table headings but no contents. Maybe there's some issue with my views function code. Thanks a lot ! Good day :)

Comment: You are welcome if the above solution solved your problem please accept it Thanks

Comment: You should use `render` rather than `render_to_response`, which is deprecated.

Comment: @DanielRoseman; You are right. I am still using the old version :(